# How to create select element with selected option in shopping cart view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

In ASP.NET Core 5 MVC shopping cart Razor view in used to create cart layout selector.

In ASP.NET MVC 4.7 it works OK but in .NET Core lines which set selected option

```
<option value="List" @(Model.LocatorViewModel.CartLayout == CartLayout.List ? "selected" : "" )>
```

show syntax error in razor editor in VS 2019:

[image]

Which is property method to create select element selected attribute in Razor?
Bootstrap 3 is used.

```
   <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
     <div class="panel-body">
      <label>
       @await I.I("Display mode")
       <select name="cartlayout" class="form-control" onchange="this.form.submit()">
       <option value="List" @(Model.LocatorViewModel.CartLayout == CartLayout.List ? "selected" : "" )>
       @await I.I("List")
       </option>

     <option value="Thumb" @(Model.LocatorViewModel.CartLayout == CartLayout.Thumb ? "selected" : "" )>
      @await I.I("Thumbnails")
      </option>
    </select>
    </label>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As error message indicated, the ['OptionTagHelper'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.taghelpers.optiontaghelper?view=aspnetcore-5.0) can not have C# in the element's attribute declaration area.

In the code you shared, it seems that the `option` works as just plain HTML `<option>` in your scenario. If so, you can try to apply [`@removeTagHelper`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-5.0#removetaghelper-removes-tag-helpers) to a specific view that would help remove the specified Tag Helper from the view.

```
@removeTagHelper Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.OptionTagHelper, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This still requires repeating same `@(Model.LocatorViewModel.CartLayout == CartLayout.XXXXX ? "selected" : "" )` in every option. Is it possible to use some built-in Select builder to avoid this  repetition? Can two element list `"Thumb", "List"` created and data binding used

Comment: `Is it possible to use some built-in Select builder to avoid this repetition?` you can provide a `List<SelectListItem>` object to [populate select tag helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-5.0#the-select-tag-helper), which enable us to specify default selected option by setting `Selected` property of  `SelectListItem`, like this `new SelectListItem { Value = "CA", Text = "Canada", Selected = true }`.